# call function located in parent from a template with a parameter in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Still newbe to Aurelia FW.
I want to execute a function located in a parent page from a template located in that parent. I have no problem doing that. The problem is that I want to take a variable\property value located in the template and use it as a parameter in the function.How can I "share" this property between the parent and the template ? 
I'm assuming that binding should be the answer.
Here's the relevant code:
This is the template instance in the parent. The relevant function to run is **changeStatus**:

```
<radio-button-switch is-active.bind="account.IsEnabled" change-state-
fuction.call="changeStatus(state)"></radio-button-switch>
```

This is the function in the parent:

```
changeStatus(statusVariable) {
  //TODO something with statusVariable
}
```

This is the template HTML:

```
   <template>
        <input type="checkbox" change.delegate="changeState($event.target.checked)">
   </template>
```

And this is the relevant code of the template (I want to execute the **changeState** function with the **isChecked** as parameter):

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';
export class radioButtonSwitch {
  @bindable changeStateFuction;

   changeState(isChecked) 
   {
      this.isElementActive = isChecked;
      this.changeStateFuction(isChecked);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you need to create "arguments object":

> If you need to invoke the function with arguments, create an object
>   whose keys are the argument names and whose values are the argument
>   values, then invoke the function with this "arguments object".

So, in your code it should be like this:

```
this.changeStateFuction({ status: isChecked });
```